# Difficulties with is_int function in PHP

Tags: php, loops

I'm writing a code to solve a problem.one of my functions is not working properly.

```
function check_factor($sqr,$num)
{
    for($i = $sqr ; true ; $i++)
    {
        $n = pow($sqr,2) - $num;
        $s = sqrt($n);
        if(is_int($s))
        {
           return $i;
        }
    }

}
```

I know that $s is a "double" , but even when I limit my loop counter to 2,I'll get an endless loop.
What am I missing here? why the function doesnt simply return null? and why I get Infinite loop even when there are 2 iterations?

Comment: You have true set as the second parameter, making it an infinite loop?

Comment: What arguments are you passing for `$sqr` and `$num`?

Comment: *I know that $s is a "double"* and you only end the function if it is an integer. **sqrt() Will always return a float**

Comment: @Valdorous as I said even when I use something like for($i=1 ; $i = 2 ; $i++)  I get infinite loop

Comment: @Mureinik for example, $sqr = 77 and $num = 5893

Comment: @Rizier123 I get that,but after let's say 2 times,it should return null,right?
so why do I get infinite loop?

Comment: Because your condition for the loop is always true

Comment: @Rizier123 as I said even when I use something like for($i=1 ; $i = 2 ; $i++) I get the same infinite loop

Comment: Here you do an assignment and `$i` holding 2 will evaluate to true. You probably mean: `$i <= 2`

Comment: @Rizier123 oh silly me... that was the problem whole time.thanks a lot ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

true is making it an infinite loop

you will always get an infinit loop because **sqrt()** returns float means

```html
$s = sqrt($n);
```

**$s** is a **float** now

and your test is testing if **$s** is an **integer** so it will be an infinit loop even after **$i=2** the loop will always stuck and the $i=2 in every loop but 
if you change the code to this

```html
<?php
function check_factor($sqr,$num)
{ 
 echo "<br>";
    for($i = 1 ; $i < 3  ; $i++)
    {
  echo " in the loop $i<br>";
        $n = pow($sqr,2) - $num;
  echo "$n<br>";
        $s = sqrt($n);
  echo "$s<br>";
        if(is_int($s))
        {
   echo "in the if <br>";
           return $i;
        }
    }
 return 0;
}
$val=0;
$val = check_factor(5,2);
echo "<br>$val<br>"; 
?>
```

the out put should be like this

```html
in the loop 1
23
4.7958315233127
in the loop 2
23
4.7958315233127

0
```

and that's it. i hope i helped.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning,I edited my post ^^
but as I said even when I use something like for($i=1 ; $i = 2 ; $i++) I get that infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual: PHP function `sqrt()` always returns a `float` and NEVER an `integer`.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqrt.php

Comment: Ok so it should just return a null,right?
why I get this endless loop?